# Python Pandas move data to new Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble loading data into a dataframe in the correct format.

The data I'm working with has the form:

```
Sensor Name,Variable,Units,Timestamp,Value,Flagged as Suspect Reading
PER_EMOTE_2202,CO,ugm -3,2019-02-15 15:46:16,476.634102929914,False
PER_EMOTE_2202,Humidity,%,2019-02-15 15:46:16,49.8,False
PER_EMOTE_2202,NO,ugm -3,2019-02-15 15:46:16,68.5581902781,False
PER_EMOTE_2202,NO2,ugm -3,2019-02-15 15:46:16,80.220623065752,False
PER_EMOTE_2202,Sound,db,2019-02-15 15:46:16,69.0,False
PER_EMOTE_2202,Temperature,Celsius,2019-02-15 15:46:16,13.2,False
PER_EMOTE_2202,CO,ugm -3,2019-02-15 15:47:16,475.363796635848,False
PER_EMOTE_2202,NO,ugm -3,2019-02-15 15:47:16,84.7920567981415,False
PER_EMOTE_2202,NO2,ugm -3,2019-02-15 15:47:16,82.3021250062142,False
PER_EMOTE_2202,Sound,db,2019-02-15 15:47:16,69.0,False
```

I'd like to load this into columns representing the value for each variable, indexed by timestamp.

For example; [Desired Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcK0h.png)

So far I have the following:

```
def load_data(path):

    df = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=['Timestamp', 'Variable', 'Units', 'Value'])
    df = df.set_index('Timestamp')

    return df
```

This produces the result; [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzT6t.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [pivot tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

```
def load_data(path):

    df = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=['Timestamp', 'Variable', 'Units', 'Value'])
    df = df.pivot_table(index='Timestamp', columns='Variable', values='Value')

    return df
```